# Custom HTML footer in Joomla is not in full width

Tags: joomla, footer

I'm designing a basic website with Joomla Protostar theme (3.3). When setting a custom HTML footer, only left 2/3rd is occupied.

I didn't change any codes in *index.php* or *template.php*

Please help!

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your site? Else simply inspect the element in your browser

Comment: Oh, I'm using still in local server (xampp). Found a module called "CUSTOM HTML ADVANCED" which boasts of eliminating "module inclusion style" in chrome. Thank you very much for the quick response.